# How Eclipse know I didn't call some method of a object?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I was supposed to call recycle after use a TypedArray, but I forgot.

Then Eclipse showed a warning saying `This TypedArray should be recycled after use with #recycle()`.

I wonder how does Eclipse know about it and how can I use this nice feature in my code.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

The warning you see here isn't a normal Java warning, but is a [Lint](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/lint.html) warning.

Lint is an error checking tool used by the Android Plugin to help you with the best practices and methods of doing things in Android.

TypedArrays can be recycled after you're done with them as a cleanup operation, and Lint simply checks to see if you've got `<TypedArrayObject>.recycle()` for each of the TypedArrays in your code anywhere. If you don't, it warns you about it.